# make the picture next to each other gridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

im using grid view and the picture seems to have spaces between each other.
what should i do to make the picture next to each other?

```
<GridView 

            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="30px" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="0dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity=""
            />
```

Comment: This is not a solution , but I have to say that using px is a bad idea. Change "30px" to "30dip" first in your width.

Comment: In addition to Andro's suggestion, how are you setting pictures into the gridview?  Do you have a custom adapter?  If yes, please add its `getView` method to the question.

Comment: @AleksG i already used getView..but it does not work.even im using no padding

Comment: paddings have nothing to do with this.  The layoutparams of the view returned from `getView` are much more important.